# KeyValuePairOfstringanyType, how do I declare and format this?

Tags: php, wsdl, dynamics-crm-2011, keyvaluepair

I have a data object in php generated from a WSDL. One variable in this data object is named "  KeyValuePairOfstringanyType" of type `KeyValuePairOfstringanyType[]`

great. How do I declare that and assign a value to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a PHP array with a single key->value and use a string for the key:

```
$someDataObject->KeyValuePairOfstringanyType = array("somekey"=>"some value");
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#

Assuming that you're creating a plugin (we're talking C# code, right)?

```
KeyValuePair<String, Object> general = new KeyValuePair<String, Object>();
KeyValuePair<String, Object> specific 
  = new KeyValuePair<String, Object>{ Key = "Konrad", Value = new Object() };
KeyValuePair<String, Object> typed 
  = new KeyValuePair<String, Object>{ Key = "Konrad", Value = "Viltersten" };
```

The first creates an empty instance. The other two have values. I put in the last one to exemplify that the *Object* instance can be pretty much anything. You're not locked to *Object* class.

Also, if you're going to have an array (a set, a bunch) of *KeyValuePair* instances, the suggested way is to use the following. The *Dictionary* instance consist of a number of such objects.

```
Dictionary<String, Objet> pairs = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
pairs.Add("key", new Object());
```

## JS

Assuming that you're talking about UI (that's be JavaScript), there's no equivalence, as JS isn't really object oriented *that way*. You could do the following.

```
var kindOfKeyValuePair = "beep";
kindOfKeyValuePair.key = "myKey";
kindOfKeyValuePair.value = "myValue";
```

However, you might as well go like this too (which differs from the C# way where you're working with strongly typed, real programming language).

```
var kindOfKeyValuePair = "beep";
kindOfKeyValuePair.notKey = "myKey";
kindOfKeyValuePair.hardlyAnyValue = "myValue";
```

## Other

Assuming that you wish to code PHP inside CRM, that's not going to happen (unless you're talking about filling an IFRAME component with an external content from a page powered by it).

Comment: I am consuming web services with PHP, the Microsoft CRM provides WSDL files that I have interpreted into PHP objects. This is microsoft's cross platform solution, wsdl files. The api methods get sent through a soap call (as configured by the WSDL) to the microsoft CRM server. Unfortunately not all of the data types that the objects want seem to translate to PHP. PHP can do key/value pairs in an array, but I'm not sure if they will come across in the format that the Microsoft CRM on the other side of the api call wants to see.

Comment: @CQM Oh, given that info, I got squat. I'm an MS junkie-monkey. No PHP for me. :)